# graceful shutdown of node/express app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I've deployed an app to Heroku, and I keep getting R12 errors sent to me from Logentries. I've  taken a look at various ways of solving this issue - but still no joy :(

Here's my bootstrap:

```
var apiService = loader.load('apiService'),
    http = require('http'),
    server,
    app;

apiService.init(); // see later

app.configure(function() {
    RedisStore = loader.load('connect-redis')(express);
    redis_store = new RedisStore(config.redis);
    /* view and routes config...*/
});

server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
    server.close();
    apiService.close();
    redis_store = null; // worth a punt?
});
```

apiService:

```
api.init = function () {
    mongoose.connect(mongourl);
};

api.close = function () {
    mongoose.connection.close();
};
```

Anyone else had this problem / got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're catching SIGTERM, you need to explicitly exit the process in your handler.

```js
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
    server.close();
    apiService.close();
    redis_store = null; // worth a punt?
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Would it not be better to pass a callback to `server.close()` and in that callback finally exit when all requests are complete?

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback